# Threejs PlaneBufferGeometry: color attribute does not show

Tags: three.js

When i create a PBG with:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(gs,gs, size - 1, size - 1);
        geometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
        var vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array;
        for (var i = 0, j = 0, l = vertices.length; i < l; i++, j += 3) {
            vertices[j + 1] = data.map[0][i];
        }
```

I dont have a color property:

[image]

Don't know if the warnings have something to do or i'm missing something. For what i can see in the code, PlaneBufferGeometry extends from BufferAttribute and should have color.

Tips?

Thanks!

Edit: Material:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
       color: 0xaaaaff,
       vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
       shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
```

Comment: what material are you using?

Comment: Hi! Added to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: remove the `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,` and you should see the material color.

Comment: Ok, will try once at home, but i want to be able to change each face's color as i was able with the standard PlaneGeometry.

Comment: @gaitat didnt work. the attribute color is not showing.

Comment: but do you see the material color? the attribute color you dont pass in so it will not show. just want to make sure that the code you have so far works.

Comment: @gaitat yes, i do see the plane in color but need the attribute. Perhaps the error has something to do that prevents the buffer to work?

Comment: the error shows up even if you comment out `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors` ?

Comment: Please note i'm creating a PBG from scratch, not converting from an existing standard geometry. I was told i should add the attribute in those cases. Will check tonight.